# Recursively display dropdown in vue js

Tags: vue.js

i have a table name called articles

```
id   parent_id  title
1        0      Profile
2        1      About Us
3        1      Why Us?
4        0      Kbow Us
```

now I want to create dropdown menu on vue laravel such that it recursively displays child category under parent category with proper indentation or - mark as per depth.E.g.:

```
<select>
<option value="1">Profile</option>
<option value="2">-About Us</option>
<option value="3">--Why Us</option>
<option value="4">Kbow Us</option>
</select>
```

I want to generate dropdown structure dynamically as like above recursively for any depth of child category in vue js.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `v-for` to make a `for loop` in vue.js.

And you can use `"-".repeat(option.parent_id)` to add a number of dashes proportional to parent_id.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#root',
  data: {
    options: [
      {'id': 1,'parent_id': 0,'title': 'Profile'},
      {'id': 2,'parent_id': 1,'title': 'About Us'},
      {'id': 3,'parent_id': 2,'title': 'Why Us?'},
      {'id': 4,'parent_id': 0,'title': 'Kbow Us'}
    ],
    selectedValue: 1
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <select v-model="selectedValue">
    <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.id">
      {{"-".repeat(option.parent_id)}}{{option.title}}
    </option>
  </select>
  <p> Selected id: {{selectedValue}}</p>
</div>
```